# How to get all instances in a subnet using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I was wondering how can you get all ec2 in a subnet when you a subnet Id

```
import boto3

ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('subnet_id')
```

This is as far as I can go but I get errors as it is only expecting an instance id

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.instances -> `ec2.instances.filter(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use filters for this...

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'SubnetID',
    'Values': [subnet_id]}])
```